# C Shell programming — user input and comparisons

Tags: shell, csh

Simple question for someone who know little C shell programming

I am posting some code lines of my program

```
........
set gramma = $<
else if ($gramma == 's') then
echo " ta defterolepta pou menoun ine " secs_remain
else if ($gramma == 'm') then
@ min = $secs_remain % 60
@ secs = $secs_remain - ($min*60)
echo " o xronos pou meni ine " min " lepta ke " secs " defterolepta "
else if ($gramma == 'h') then
.........
```

My question is about the character. As you can see I am reading a character from the keyboard.
On the `if` command, does my character need the `'` and `'`?

Or can i simply write the character?

For example

```
if ($gramma == 's') then
```

or

```
if ($gramma == s) then
```

I know that if it was a string it will be

```
if ($gramma == "sexy") then
```

and if a number

```
if ($gramma == 4) then
```

What about a single character?

Comment: It would be best for you to just try to do your homework yourself.  Just try it.

Comment: Voting to close. This is YOUR homework, do that stuff yourself.

Comment: you guys who say do your home work urself etc . what are u talking about . all i am asking is to tell me which one is correct because i CANT find it in my notes or the internet .

Comment: type it into an editor and run it.

Comment: i just posted 10 lines from a 50 lines code i made and i asked for a simple question . im not asking to solve any code for me . dont be rude

Comment: im not idiot , if i could run it , i wouldnt be here , i could very easily create a simple program reading a character and printing it . but i cant run the program right now . its just a simple question , what wrong with that ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking should the right hand side of a comparison always be wrapped in single quote chars? == 'm' (right hand side)

AND OF course, the answer is it depends

Single quotes mean that any variable values inside will NOT be expanded to the value that was assigned. If you you have variable values, quote them with double-quote chars.

You can leave out single OR double quotes if you're *really,really,really* sure you're never going to have a value on the right-hand-side that evaluates to a multi-'word' value with white space chars. You really need quoting (single or double) to avoid problems with white space chars.

I think the general consensus among people that write books about shell coding is that you always want to surround the left-and-right-hand sides of a string comparison operations (==, !=, ~=) with appropriate quotes, double if variable expansion required, single if not.